# Add extra row height except the first for "array"

Tags: tables, line-spacing, arrays

I know for `tabular`, there is `\extrarowheight` that can add the extra row height to every row. Now I have a special purpose that I must need the `array` environment. However, `\extrarowheight` does not work in `array`. If I don't want to manually put `\\[1ex]` at each line, is there a way to add the extra row height in `array`? Moreover, I want the vertical space of first line to be unchanged.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{15pt} % not work
$\begin{array}{l}\hline cccc\\cccc\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline ccdd\\cccc\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline ccdd\\ccgg\\\hline\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Output: [image]
Explanation: I do want the top line be adjacent to the top glyph of the letter,  like *c*, *d*, etc. This is why I previously set the `\arraystretch` to be `0`. (Otherwise, the short letters like *c* will leave the top line if it is the tallest letter appear in that row!)
[image]

Comment: you could use `\hline\noalign{\vspace{2pt}}`

Comment: you can use `\extrarowheight` with `array` (which is really the same thing as `tabular` apart from using math mode  in some places) (setting `\arraystretch` to 0 makes the array spacing verry inconsistent)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it to be`\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}\setlength{\extrarowheight}{15pt}
$\begin{array}{l}\hline cccc\\cccc\\\hline\end{array}$`? However, it appears nothing changes for me. I guess the `\arraystretch` prevented the `\extrarowheight` from changing.

Comment: you had not provided a test example otherwise I may have posted more code. (I see Skillmon has provided one now, but it should have been in the question) I do not think you want arraystretch or extrarowheight at all, just use vspace as I suggested but with a negative space as Skillmon has shown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I have found that I forgot to mention that I'd already adjust the `\arraystretch`. Sorry about that.. Now I edit.

Comment: but it is hard to imagine any case where setting arraystretch to 0 does something good.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}[]{l}
  \hline
  \noalign{\vspace{-1ex}}
  cccc\\
  cccc\\
  \hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Though I definitely do *not* encourage the following, it does what you asked. Still, I don't think this is a good idea and you should not use it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
$\begin{array}[]{l}
  \hline
  \noalign{\vspace{-1ex}}
  dcccc\\
  cccc\\
  \hline
\end{array}$
\bgroup
\newcommand\mystretchedbackslash{\renewcommand\\[1][2ex]{\tabularnewline[##1]}}%
\def\arraystretch{0}%
$\begin{array}[]{>{\mystretchedbackslash}l}
  \hline
  dcccc\\
  cccc\\[1ex]
  \hline
\end{array}$
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. But one more thing, can I automatically set the vertical space? (i.e., don't need to type`\\[2ex]` at every end of row.)

Comment: @Eric I don't quite get what you want. There is no `\\[2ex]` in my code, only one negative `\vspace`. Do you intend to use your `\def\arraystretch{0}` approach and put space there by using `\\[2ex]` syntax? If so: *why*?

Comment: @Eric  you should use skillmon's original answer, shown first here, and if you want the bottom line to touch add a similar vspace before the final `\hline`

Comment: @Skillmon I have edited my post to be clearer. Actually I want to use `\left\{ \begin{array}cccc\\ddd \end{array}\right.`, with the brackets `{` as tall as `c`, if it is the tallest letter in that line.

Comment: @Eric your question doesn't even mention `\{` ????

Comment: Ya I didn't mention. Because I thought I should directly ask the question in terms of `array`, automatic row height, etc... (And then the `\{` issue will be solved.) Since I wonder how this problem can be solved as well. (Then I can apply the skill to future circumstances.)

Comment: @Skillmon I was mistaken something when I first reply you. I pharse it again: In fact, the output result I exact want can be generated by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}$\begin{array}[]{l}\hline ccccc\\[2ex]cccc\\[2ex]cccc\\[2ex]cccc\\\hline\end{array}$` Then, how to get rid of manually typing the `[2cm]` in each row? Or can such code be written in a better way?

Comment: @Skillmon And the new version of your answer works for me. However how to make the bottom line adjacent to the glyph of the text in the last row? Is it correct to achieve so by using `\\[0ex]\hline` after the last row?

Comment: (Although for my real need, I don't need to use `\hline`, but it is a auxiliary line to see what is the real bottom of the whole `array` environment.)

Comment: @Eric `\\[0pt]` (or `0ex`) would work. Still, you shouldn't use it. The `\\[2ex]` doesn't give consistent spacing. You should just add the correct amount of `\noalign{\vspace{-<space>}}`.

Comment: I don't know how to get the typsetting I want using `\noalign`. All I can get using `\noalign` is the same as your output in the **left** hand side of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3wPq.png), the is letter `d` is pierced by the line which is not I want.

Comment: @Eric -- i think you're going to have a tough time using `\left\{` and getting braces only the height of what's on the line.  `\left` (and `\right`) only *enlarge* the delimiters; they don't shrink them.  if `\left` is involved and you want a good answer, that has to be part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks?  The default is 3pt between row data, but the default can be changed with `\setstackgap{S}{...}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{15pt} % not work
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{cccc\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{ccdd\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{ccdd\\ccgg}\\\hline\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You also have the choice of short stacks (constant interrow gap) or long stacks (constant interrow baselineskip).  Changing your data slightly shows the difference...top row, short; bottom row, long:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{ccdg\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{ccdd\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Shortstack[l]{ccdd\\ccgg}\\\hline\end{array}$
\bigskip

$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Longstack[l]{ccdg\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Longstack[l]{ccdd\\cccc}\\\hline\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{l}\hline \Longstack[l]{ccdd\\ccgg}\\\hline\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]